# Points of SQL failure and moving ahead to NOSQL

Tags: sql, database, nosql, comparison

I have experience over Relational DB's but very little over NoSQL data stores and for these two I need a well defined reason to say that one needs to move to NoSQL.

Since I cannot replicate a situation where I can push a DB to its limits and make it lose performance, let alone scaling it. Therefore wondered about to see what others had to say. May be I have been treading the wrong path path, but I have read people saying why we should move to NoSQL or how or even at what sort of different scenarios eventually leads to NoSQL. Article after article explains what Big Data is and how it is managed in the NoSQL domain and how useful it is with it architecture of being scalable, robust, ACID, BASE, Data modelling from Sql to NoSQL, etc features.

But none would provide some solid numbers. E.g. A web service that had a DB of X-TB's and eventually the queries (read/write/etc) took T-seconds or so to complete so we moved on to NoSQL to get back the performance. My concern is at what point it really did a team shift to NoSQL when they said, OK we're done with scaling and everything, lets move on to NoSQL!

So I have had to ask SO users. Maybe someone can share some valuable information.  This seems to be an open issue for me as I have been trying to get hold of even just one document that explains a real case scenario where the SQL DB eventually had to be replaced with a NoSQL DB/DS/storage.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that NoSQL is ACID?  Isn't that mutually exclusive from BASE?

Comment: Well some are compliant to ACID http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html and actually I just summarized what I had read. You might be right.

Comment: Realtional datbases are more scalable than web developers think. But they require extensive expertise to design large databases (and at the design stage not ten years later) and that means database developers NOT application developers. I know people successfully running terrabyte-sized relational datbases.

Comment: Close. Answer is always "it depends"

Comment: TFD is right.  It always depends.  I can completely understand why a site like, say, Amazon would need a solution away from mainstream relational databases, but I have a very hard time believing very many sites/apps need that kind of solution.  It has always seemed to me that , as has been noted, bad performance is due to Java developers or .NET developers thinking they are design a database and write good SQL.  Design well.  Code well.  You can go far without the (IMHO questionable) NoSQL shiney bauble.